# Using 'Like' with the Facebook Graph API on iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

I am using the latest Facebook SDK for iOS and Graph API. Works Great.

I'm trying to 'Like' status updates, doing the following:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *messageID = (NSString*)[managedObject valueForKey:@"message_id"];

NSLog(@"Like: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", messageID]);

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", messageID] andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

However this returns an error from Facebook:

> facebookErrDomain error 10000.

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out. You cannot pass nil to the parameters. So I created an empty `NSMutableDictionary`, and passed that. Worked fine. (By the way: [it’s not possible to like a page this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837010).)