# integrate facebook with like button in android and iphone

Tags: iphone, android, facebook

I want to integrate facebook with like button in android and iphone. I integrated facebook in android and iphone also but i didn't integrate like button . So please tell me how to integrate the facebook like button in android and also in iphone.

For integrate the facebook i used below link example in android

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Now i have to integrate the facebook like button.

Best Regards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question in mind? Or are you just trying to get someone to write it for you?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no like button in facebook graph api. There are some alternatives that you can select. First you can use a webview and show the like button in a webview.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Another alternative is using facebook share functionality in facebook-android-sdk.

Last and more general alternative is using an intent and let the user select how to share it. (it can be any app including facebook)

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT HERE!");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR TEXT HERE");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "YOUR TITLE HERE"));
```

Comment: Using the intent doesn't work, beacuse the Facebook for Android app is broken and doesn't handle the  intent in the correct way (the message is not populated).

Answer (score 5):

Check out this nice bit of code: http://angelolloqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

Add the FBLikeButton class to your view:

```
FBLikeButton *likeButton = [[FBLikeButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 372, 320, 44)  
andUrl:@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/De-Zilk/108209735867960"];
```

Thanks a lot Angel García Olloqui

Answer (score 4):

From:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

(I've removed the https prefix from the graph urls since I don't have enough stackoverflow rep to post more than two hypelinks..)

> Publishing
>
> You can publish to the Facebook graph
>   by issuing HTTP POST requests to the
>   appropriate connection URLs, using an
>   access token. For example, you can
>   post a new wall post on Arjun's wall
>   by issuing a POST request to
>       graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed:
>
> curl -F 'access_token=...' \
>        -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
>             graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
>
> The Graph API reference provides more
>   detailed information on the supported
>   arguments and their corresponding
>   values.
>
> **You can comment on or like any object
>   that has a /comments or /likes
>   connection by posting to
>        graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments
>   and
>        graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes,
>   respectively:**
>
> **curl -F 'access_token=...'
>         graph.facebook.com/313449204401/likes**
>
> Most write operations require extended
>   permissions for the active user. See
>   the authentication guide for details
>   on how you can request extended
>   permissions from the user during the
>   authentication step.

Comment: Also note that, according to the below post, and from my work, you can't 'like' an FB page, just posts, comments and photos ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837010/facebook-api-liking-page-on-behalf-of-user-extended-permissions

Comment: this is related with this bug http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714#c46