# android facebook like

Tags: android

I want to integrate a like button in my android app. I used the code

```
likeWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1 );
 likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 String url = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" +
           "href=" + URLEncoder.encode("likeurl" ) + "&" +
           "layout=standard&" +
           "show_faces=false&" +
           "width=500&" +
           "action=like&" +
           "colorscheme=light&" +
           "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode( "read_stream" );
likeWebView.loadUrl( url );
```

But after login it is showing a blank page. 
Please give me a solution to add  a Like button.

Comment: check this post, there is well-formed library to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private initLikeButton( String urlToLike ) {
   likeWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.likeWebView );
   likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String url = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" +
       "href=" + URLEncoder.encode( urlToLike ) + "&" +
       "layout=standard&" +
       "show_faces=false&" +
       "width=375&" +
       "action=recommend&" +
       "colorscheme=light&" +
       "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode( FacebookAdapter.getInstance().getAccessToken() );

likeWebView.loadUrl( url );
```

Here, in your code you must be put **likeurl** , url that like.

using the iframe code provided by the like button code generator at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like. But since an iframe is basically the same thing as a WebView, it seemed redundant to load the code in an iframe and then load the iframe in a WebView. So instead I just loaded the code that would be in the iframe directly into the WebView using the code below. But the same thing happens either way.

Incidentally, the same issue exists when developing an iPhone app. We don't want the user to have to login to facebook every time they run our app. But unfortunately, if the user has logged into facebook on another computer since the last time they logged into facebook via our app, they'll have to log in again.

On the android platform I would think a better solution might be to have a facebook app that you send an intent to that takes care of keeping the user logged in and returning the html for rendering the like button.

see more: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/17

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

[integrate facebook with like button in android and iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935034/integrate-facebook-with-like-button-in-android-and-iphone)

Comment: thanks a lot for giving me asolution.but now getting an error on FacebookAdapter class.do i have to import any library file to get that class.

Comment: this code is not working now.it is showing login page but not liking the page.please help me..

Comment: What is FacebookAdapter class ?

Answer (score 8):

Finally Facebook and Launched [Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button) Button for Android

Steps:

1 - Add [Facebook Library](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip) to Project

2 - [Create App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/async/create/platform-setup/dialog/) on Facebook
3 - Update Manifest

```
**In the Application tab add meta-data**

<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fb_id" />
```

4 - Add LikeView in Layout

```
//activitymain.xml
<com.facebook.widget.LikeView
            android:id="@+id/like_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </com.facebook.widget.LikeView>
```

5 - ActivityMain.java

```
//set facebook page or link to this like button
LikeView likeView;
UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
    likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/<page_username>");//it can be any link

    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
    likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
    likeView.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, null);

}
```

Output 
[image]

Comment: when i close the app and open it again the button is back to like and have to press it again. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers work; I am just building on top of what is already above. In actually implementing their solution I found that the device's default browser would open because the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` was not being set.

Also, I changed it from `recommended` to `like` (I know little things like that can piss people off if they're looking for copy & paste code - I've gotten ticked at that :P).

> The following is code that is working as of July 25th 2012.

**THIS IS ONLY THE LIKE BUTTON** change the width/height if you want the other stuff in the webView.

---

### Java

```
    WebView likeWebView = new WebView(this);
    likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            likeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }


    });

    String url = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" +
               "href=" + URLEncoder.encode( "[yout_url]" ) + "&" +
               "layout=standard&" +
               "show_faces=false&" +
               "width=375&" +
               "action=like&" +
               "colorscheme=light&" +
               "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode( mApp.facebook.getAccessToken() );

    likeWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

### Layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/fb_likeWebView"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp" />
```

Cheers! :D

Comment: Not working anymore :-( See the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464570/facebook-like-button-in-webview-with-sdk