# Like button in facebook integration in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated the facebook in my android application and need to give the facility of "like" how can  i do this please help me...

thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [integrate facebook with like button in android and iphone](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5935034/integrate-facebook-with-like-button-in-android-and-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no like button in Facebook graph Api

Try this post [integrate facebook with like button in android and iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935034/integrate-facebook-with-like-button-in-android-and-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

There is no like button in the facebook gaprh api

So its best to use webview and show the like button in this
here is my recent complete answer [link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9151296/1115454) to how to setup like button

but remember if your app is only caring the webview you can't able to register your app