# android facebook sdk 3.0 custom like button

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android.

how make a custom likes button

```
Request request = new Request(session, page_id + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,  new Callback()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response)
    {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, response.toString());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (response.getGraphObject() != null)
        {
            //Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, response.toString());
        }
    }
});
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

page_id = 417732304946490

has OAuthException
(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

no way use in app like ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935034/integrate-facebook-with-like-button-in-android-and-iphone

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook graph API does not provide the feature to Like the facebook page. Instead you can open a webview with your page URL, so that your can Log in and Like your page.

```
 // To open webview
 String url = "your page URL";
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 startActivity(i);
```