# Like fan page within iPhone app via Graph API or Open graph?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

It seems like the only way I can add a fan page "like" button is to [use UIWebView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iPhone-app).

I personally don't like this method and I'd much prefer to be able to like the page via the Graph API, similarly to what explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837010/liking-a-page-on-behalf-of-a-user)
the last answer by ToddH was that it's possible to "like" a fan page via the Graph API. According to Stan's answer however, it seems like you can't like a fan page via the Graph API, as it's against Facebook's platform policies, but you can like via Open graph (which I haven't used yet).

In short: Can I use Graph API to like a fan page? If not is my only option is to use UIWebView (as explained in Ray's tutorial), or I have a new option to use Facebook's Open graph? (please elaborate on this option if it's legit)

EDIT: the short answer is no, you can't use Graph API/Open Graph to like a fan page. See my answer below.

Also I want to add that I don't understand why it was so important to down vote this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: I added a comment to the answer suggesting it was possible with the Built-in Like action in OPen Graph - it is not possible, and that's mentioned in the docs

Comment: Oh, OK, I see that you know what you're talking about ;-). So my only option is to embed a UIWebView, similar to what Ray's explains in his tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Igy, who works at Facebook, wrote in the comments above, there is no way to do it directly via Graph API nor via Open Graph.

In my project I have added a button when clicked navigates to the facebook fan page via UIWebView and from there the user can Like the page.