# Facebook like with sharekit on iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-like, sharekit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 'like' facebook application page, how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620153/ios-like-facebook-application-page-how-to-do-it)

i build a web site and it has a facebook like button. i handled the link of the like button and want to make it with sharekit.
For example, i can handle share button and share it with sharekit but i cannot do it for like button also.
Did anybody something like that or is there any other way to this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to allow a user to like a link or page or anything is to embed the iframe/xfbml like button code in a UIWebView control.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an agreement on not being able to do this. However, this post shows you can:
[Using 'Like' with the Facebook Graph API on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281665/using-like-with-the-facebook-graph-api-on-ios)

To back it up, here's an excerpt from FB Graph API documentation:

> You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes
>   connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments
>   and https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes, respectively:

(source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Comment: roger - should I delete my answers? will that help?

Comment: the mystery lies in your answer mate, the OBJECT_ID is the key, the webpage you are going to like is not part of the facebook graph hence does not have any OBJECT_ID and still you want to like that webpage. that is what the Facebook LIKE button does.