# Any API for implementing Facebook 'Like ' feature in my app in iphone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Like button in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087660/like-button-in-ios-application)

I want to create a Facebook  like button ,on clicking that button i want to implement 'like'  Facebook page feature in my app  in iPhone.

Comment: You can't. The only way to like a page (or what ever) is through the 'like' button facebook provides

Comment: check my answer, you will get the like button of that particular page, wherever you need in your app, there is no any API to  get "like button"
!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the latest method to get facebook like button is given below,

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=%@&send=false&layout=button_count&width=90&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font=arial&height=21",self.href];

//store the page link that you need to like in href

```
NSURLRequest *fbLikeURLRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[_webView loadRequest:fbLikeURLRequest];
```

Use this web view where you need to get like button !

reger developers.facebook.com if you need to know more

Regards

Deepak

Comment: Thanks for this code,it works,but how can i trace that whether user has click on like button or not...As per my app requirement i want to know whether user likes the page or not...

Comment: for all other actions check this project https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView

Comment: and for like button, use my method, the method that they use in this sample project is expired