# iOS Game - implementation of "star" and "like" buttons in gamecenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

Good evening,

I'm working on implementation game center to my iOS game and I want create achievements, which players will raise when they will rate app on the main board in game center and when they will like it on facebok using game center.

But I don't have any idea how to check it. Is possible, for example, catch events of those buttons (stars and like buttons) in game ceneter, or what way should I go?
I think if those buttons are in game center there should be some kind of cooperation with Objective-c.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to determine when an action is performed on either of those buttons in the Game Center view. Unfortunately, there is no solid way of determining when a user rates your app. As for determining if they have liked it on Facebook, you might want to try having them connect with Facebook and select a like button from within your app instead of from Game Center. Here is a link that may help with that: [Like button in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087660/like-button-in-ios-application)